# Setting up mailgun with a real domain

Tags: mailgun, spf, dkim

I am trying to set up mailgun with a real domain (meaning not with sandbox99887@.mailgun.org).
When coming to domain verification I hit a problem.

The SPF entry has been successfully verified within 5 minutes.
On the other hand the DKIM entry is still not good after much longer.

If it is only because it is taking more time, it is OK.
But I fear I may have done some setting wrong that could be the cause of the problem.

Anyone had this kind of experience before?

Comment: This is not an SO question, and it's very vague. What have you done? What is not working? Be specific & detailed.

Comment: Could you post more details? For example, your SPF record would go in the the root domain's DNS (example.com) assuming that's where you want to send email "From," whereas DKIM would be a sub domain such as default._domainkey.example.com or something like that.

Comment: Please also post the DKIM entry. A common error I've seen is that people will put the DKIM TXT record in the root domain when it's a sub domain (e.g., specifically an A record). 
SPF @ --> TXT value
DKIM something.example.com --> TXT value